# Equivalent command for "odl-openflowplugin-all" in ODL Nitrogen

Tags: karaf, opendaylight

I want to install all the features related to openflowplugin in ODL Nitrogen but `feature:install odl-openflowplugin-all` is not being accepted as a valid command. If I am not wrong this used to work with older ODL releases but here its not.

Please Suggest!

Comment: there is no feature called **odl-openflowplugin-all** in ODL Nitrogen ,you can check with following command feature:list | grep odl-openflowplugin-all

Comment: I know about that. Hence would need a way to achieve this with the minimum number of commands instead of installing each feature one by one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about odl-openflowplugin-all, but I notice it's not there in either of the official [Carbon](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/groups/public/org/opendaylight/integration/distribution-karaf/0.6.3-Carbon/distribution-karaf-0.6.3-Carbon.zip) or [Nitrogen](https://nexus.opendaylight.org/content/repositories/public/org/opendaylight/integration/karaf/0.7.2/karaf-0.7.2.zip) releases.

here is what I see for Nitrogen:

```
opendaylight-user@root>feature:list | grep odl-openflowplugin
odl-openflowplugin-app-notifications             | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-notifications             | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-onf-extensions                | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-onf-extensions                | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: ONF Extensions
odl-openflowplugin-app-southbound-cli            | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-southbound-cli            | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-bulk-o-matic              | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-bulk-o-matic              | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-forwardingrules-sync      | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-forwardingrules-sync      | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-topology                  | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-topology                  | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-flow-services                 | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-flow-services                 | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Flow Services
odl-openflowplugin-app-config-pusher             | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-config-pusher             | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions                | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-nxm-extensions                | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Nicira Extensi
odl-openflowplugin-app-forwardingrules-manager   | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-forwardingrules-manager   | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-app-reconciliation-framework  | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-reconciliation-framework  | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-southbound                    | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | openflowplugin-0.5.2                             | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Li southbound
odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer       | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-app-table-miss-enforcer       | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Application -
odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest            | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest            | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Flow Services
odl-openflowplugin-nsf-model                     | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-nsf-model                     | OpenDaylight :: OpenflowPlugin :: NSF :: Model
odl-openflowplugin-drop-test                     | 0.5.2            |          | Uninstalled | odl-openflowplugin-drop-test                     | OpenDaylight :: Openflow Plugin :: Drop Test
opendaylight-user@root>
```

I think you will probably get what you want (just guessing) if you
install odl-openflowplugin-flow-services-rest. That brings in a lot
of different things as dependencies. You can check it out with:

```
feature:list -i | grep odl-
```

Comment: Thanks jamo. So, does this mean that there no command available to install all the features starting from Carbon? What if I need to install all the features related to dlux using command `feature:install odl-dlux-all`?

Comment: you can install multiple features on the command line, just put a space between them. Or, you can edit the fetures file in etc/ to add whatever features you want in the featuresBoot variable.

Comment: ok thank you...so basically it means I have to enter each feature to get it installed. There is no magic "all" command available after Carbon?

Comment: there is a way to install the whole kitchen sink, if that's what you want, but that will bring in a ton of other features from OpenDaylight in general. change your features config files variables (featuresRepositories and featuresBoot) to look like what is in this log file: https://logs.opendaylight.org/releng/vex-yul-odl-jenkins-1/ovsdb-csit-1node-upstream-southbound-all-carbon/270/console.log.gz  Careful with the version strings in those values so that they match the version you are using. Then you can install the feature "old-integration-compatible-with-all"

Comment: btw, that log file I put above will expire in aprox 6 months.